# Ember.js dynamic child views

Tags: ember.js, sproutcore-2

I'm having trouble getting ember to render a dynamic child view. It seems that once the child view is rendered, the binding is lost. Here's a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zaius/XYzfa/

As you click between the two editor pages, the child view remains on the first view that was rendered. Is there a way to tell ember to refresh the view, or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

I'm brand new to ember, so any general feedback on my code is welcome too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using `Ember.ContainerView` (see [documentation](http://emberjs.com/#toc_41)) for such dynamic content.

Illustrating [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/XYzfa/6/) (I also refactored your code a little to be more idiomatic).

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks so much. A quick question - when / from where does updateForm get called? I can't find any reference to it in the docs.

Comment: Ah, got it. The function name means nothing - it's just called whenever |editor| changes as that function is an observer. Thanks for the help!