# My fake case statement in Emberjs is blowing up. What's the right way?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to render a different handlebars template based on the current value of a property in my model, and there could be quite a few options (hence I'd rather not use a lot of `{{#if}}`s). The best thing I can think of is this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('selectorType', function(name, options) {
  return Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{template _selectors_" + name + "}}")(options.contexts[0], options);
});
```

And I use that in my template like:

```
{{selectorType selector.name}}
```

(instead of like a hundred `{{#if}}`s)

The problem is that I get this error during render: *"You can't use appendChild outside of the rendering process"*

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this using a ContainerView with dynamic childViews, see [Ember.js dynamic child views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795398/ember-js-dynamic-child-views) for a discussion on how.

The relevant code is (coffeescript):

```
App.SelectorType = Ember.Object.extend
  name: null
  type: null
  typeView: null
  options: null

App.SelectorTypes = [
  App.SelectorType.create(
    name: 'foo'
    type: 'bar'
  ) #, more etc
]

App.SelectorTypes.forEach (t) ->
  t.set 'typeView', Ember.View.create
    templateName: "selectors/_#{t.get('viewType')}_view"
    name: t.get('name')

App.SelectorDetailView = Ember.ContainerView.extend
  didInsertElement: ->
    @updateForm()

  updateForm: (->
    type = @get('type')
    typeObject = App.SelectorTypes.findProperty('type', type)
    return if Ember.isNone(type)

    view = typeObject.get('typeView')
    @get('childViews').forEach (v) -> v.remove()
    @get('childViews').clear()
    @get('childViews').pushObject(view)
  ).observes('type')
```

And the template:

```
  Selector Type:
  {{view Ember.Select
        viewName=select
        contentBinding="App.SelectorTypes"
        optionValuePath="content.type"
        optionLabelPath="content.name"
        prompt="Pick a Selector"
        valueBinding="selector.type"
  }}
<dl>
  <dt><label>Details</label></dt>
  <dd>
    {{view App.SelectorDetailView typeBinding="selector.type"}}
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Seems too hard, though, would be interested to see better solutions!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any need to create a helper to do this. You can do it from within the view by modifying the `templateName` and then calling the `rerender` method once you've changed its `templateName`:

```
init: function() {
    this.set('templateName', 'firstOne');
    this._super();
},

click: function() {
    this.set('templateName', 'secondOne');
    this.rerender();
}
```

We can use the `init` method for setting the empty `templateName` before the template has been rendered. We'll then call the `_super` method to complete the insertion of the view into the DOM. We can then trigger the change of the view on the click event. We update the `templateName` variable and then call `rerender()` to re-render this particular view.

I've set you up a JSFiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/pFkaE/ try clicking on "First One." to change the view to the `secondOne`.

Comment: That's interesting, but it's not bound to my model at all. Do you know how I would carry that property from my model into the tmeplateName on this view?

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/pFkaE/1/ so that the model and the controller are in the `IndexView`, but then you have a sub-view which you can change accordingly?

Comment: Thanks for your help, see my answer for how I ended up solving it :)